# Have HTML table to expand downward only with new data CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am adding a table to my website and I need the table to only expand downward when new data is added. Now whenever I add a couple rows of new data to the table the table extends past the beginning of the website and the top I have set for it. The code needs to be able to work with any amount of entries so this will not work. Is there any solution to this issue I am facing? Thanks for any help in advance!

HTML:

```
<style>
    #table {
      border-color: #fff;
    }
    td {
      border: 2px solid #fff;
    }
    table {
      z-index: 3;
      position: absolute;
      background: #011721;
      font-size: 2em;
      top: 600px;
      font-weight: 600;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
   </style>
        <table id='table1'>
          <body class="text">
            <table style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
               <thead>
                  <td>Number</td>
                  <td>Name</td>
                  <td>Price</td>
               </thead>
               
               {% for row in rows %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{row["Number"]}}</td>
                    <td> {{row["Name"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{row["Price"]}}</td>
                  </tr>
               {% endfor %}
            </table>
         </body>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why is there a `<body>` tag inside a `<table>`?

Comment: I removed it and it didn't effect the table

Comment: @Python123 If I understand correctly, you should use the top margin value in dynamic form(%) or you should use bottom margin instead of using top margin.

Comment: Hello thank you for your response! I have tried using it in % form such as top: 100% but when adding more layers the table still is shifting up. How would I implement margin-bottom to solve this issue as the number of rows can vary by a lot?